# Fetch row with the highest id column value

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to reuse a query with concatenation but It seems not working.

I have this for counting rows (working):

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT id, image_date, image_link, image_name, image_category FROM image WHERE image_date < NOW() AND image_category= :category";
$q->bindValue(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
$row = $q->fetchColumn();
```

And I would like to concatenate with that to use data (not working):

```
$q .= " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :limit");
$q->bindValue(':limit', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->execute();
```

I've also test with that form but not working :

```
$q=$q. " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :limit");
```

Comment: you're going to have to edit your question as to its exact placement of what you tried.

Comment: your first query does anything but count. you have to check your premises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with PDO is that you have to prepare a query before you can bind anything, and once prepared, a query obviously cannot be extended anymore.

Besides, your first query does anything but count. So the simpler the better - just run two separate queries without concatenation

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM image WHERE image_date < NOW() AND image_category= ?";
$q->execute([$category]);
$count = $q->fetchColumn();
```

And then

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT id, image_date, image_link, image_name, image_category 
 FROM image WHERE image_date < NOW() AND image_category= ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?";
$q->execute([$category, $limit]);
$rows = $q->fetchall();
```

Comment: Ok this is the answer I wanted to hear. So I should do two requests. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the second part to the SQL string,
but not to the Prepared Statement variable `$q`.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, image_date, image_link, image_name, " .
    "image_category FROM image WHERE image_date < NOW() " .
    "AND image_category= :category ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :limit";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->bindValue(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindValue(':limit', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->execute();
$row = $q->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: what does fetchColumn() to do here?

Comment: I added that statement from the original question. Here `fetchColumn()` will return the `id` of the first result row, or `FALSE` if there are no rows.

Comment: This will not return the same result from my first statement.